# Фигурные окна javafx

Tags: java, gui, javafx, swing

Как сделать фигурные окна в `javafx`? Куда копать? И можно ли сделать фигурные в `swing`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, удобнее будет сделать на `fx`, ибо можно и даже нужно использовать css